# How to ensure that byte array has converted data from double datatype

Tags: java, arrays, double, bytebuffer

I am getting the output

```
[B@3a2fc571

byte[] rate = new byte[8];
ByteBuffer.wrap(rate).putDouble(Flow_Rate);
```

I used the function to write this data 
`of_vendor.setData(rate);`
But the capacity is same and it is not writing that byte after using the function when the function accept array of `byte[]`.
after converting it to `ByteBuffer` the output is same and the output is

```
java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=0 cap=8]
```

Comment: You seem to be printing the array itself instead of its contents. Try `Arrays.toString(rate);`

Comment: What do you expect the output to be and why?

Comment: I want to write that byte buffer using the function
i created an object of the class and using the function of that class to write some data on it. but the array is created but when i am using the function it is giving the contents of an array rather the data is not written on to it. Why?

Answer (score -1):

wrap is an static method of ByteBuffer and returns a new instance of ByteBuffer, you must capture the instance and then manipulate it, try something like this:

```
byte[] rate = new byte[8];
ByteBuffer obj = ByteBuffer.wrap(rate)
obj.putDouble(Flow_Rate);
...
return obj
```

Comment: I already used this technique still the size is  zero and the capacity is not changing it is same. means it i created array of 8 it is same.

Comment: in my code i'm using this method

`ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(msgLength);
   bb.put(REPLY_BEGIN);
   bb.put(ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(msgLength).array());
   bb.put(Hex.decodeHex(msg.getTid().toCharArray()), 0, 7);
   bb.put(Hex.decodeHex(msg.getCmd().toCharArray()), 0, 2);
   bb.put(message.getBody());
   bb.put(ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort(checksum(bb.array(), msgLength - 4)).array());
   bb.put(ENDLINE);
`